# How to use the Drupal flashcard module?

Tags: 7

I am not very familiar with Drupal modules.

I am using Drupal 7, and installed the [Flashcard](http://drupal.org/project/flashcard) module. I enabled it, the flashcard-cycle module, and the libraries module; I also added the jquery plug-in as \sites\all\libraries\jquery.cycle\jquery.cycle.min.js.

I am getting the flashcard content type in structure/content types, but I don't know what else I have to do.

I need further instructions about what I need to do in order to use the flashcard module.  What is my next step?

Answer (score 2):

Go to this content type's "Manage  fields" page and add new field with "Flashcard" type. Set number values you want (I think you will need Unlimited). Go to "Manage display" page and change your new field formatter from "Default" to "Cycle". Create a new node with a couple of Flashcard pairs.